# "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cookiesProvider <- $cookies <- PageTopCtrl

Tags: angularjs

I am using the blur-admin theme and developing my project. I have enabled an authentication mechanism that passes through *webgate* and gets a username via cookie into the application. We validate the username and then login to the application and display username on right hand side at the top of the dashboard page.

Somehow, the cookie is not getting captured in the code. Kindly let me know where am I going wrong in adding `ngCookies` feature to my project.

Upon running application, I am facing the error that's pasted in the subject of this email.

Kindly help.

Comment: **pageTop.directive.js**
angular.module('BlurAdmin.theme.components')
            .directive('pageTop', pageTop).controller('PageTopCtrl', PageTopCtrl);
function PageTopCtrl($scope,$cookies) {
 $scope.username ="";
 var cookie = $cookies.get('UCM_INFO');     
 console.log("Cookie=" + cookie);
  if (cookie !== null) {
  var email = cookie.split("~");
  $scope.username = email[email.length - 1];
  }
}

Comment: **index.html**
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.0/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: The above code does not work and it displays "{{username}} instead of proper email id .
If i  modify code as below, it goes into infinite loop trying to open browsers again and again.

**pageTop.directive.js**
angular.module('BlurAdmin.theme.components',['ngCookies'])